# Unable to fetch data from mongoDB using node.js and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I could not fetch data from collection using node.js and mongoose. My collection is given below.

hl_user:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5d7773fc7c213e60b8fb8f77"
    },
    "name": "admin",
    "login_name": "admin",
    "password": "ecd00aa1acd325ba7575cb0f638b04a5",
    "status": "1",
    "user_type": "1"
}
```

Here is my code:

model.admin.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var use=new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    login_name: String,
    password: String,
    status: Number,
    user_type: Number
})
var User = mongoose.model('hl_user', use);
module.exports = User;
```

adminController.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mden = require('md5');
var User =  require('../model/model.admin');


module.exports.signin = (req, res, next) =>{
    var uname=req.body.username;
    var password=req.body.password;
    var pass=mden(password);
    //console.log('docs',pass,uname);
    User.find({},(err, docs) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('docs',docs);
            if (docs && docs.length > 0) {
                var data={'status':200,"msg":"Success"};
                res.send(data);
            }else{
                var data={'status':400,"msg":"Failed"};
                res.send(data);
            }
        }else{
            console.log('err',err);
        }
    })
}
```

Here in console I am getting the blank value. Here I need to fetch the values from `hl_user`.

Comment: what is the console error that you get can you put it up

Comment: @Sathiraumesh: I am getting err as null and docs=[].

Comment: Set the collection option in your schema definition Set this option if you need a different name for your collection.

`var userSchema = new Schema({..}, { collection: 'hl_user' }); var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);` or just add the collection name as the third argument `var User = mongoose.model('User', use, 'hl_user');`

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your model like as follow ,

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var use = new Schema({
    name: String,
    login_name: String,
    password: String,
    status: Number,
    user_type: Number
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('hl_user', use);
```

Everything else looks fine .